# How to suitably choose the correct unit for datetime?

Tags: python

I have a list of datetimes which I have converted to relative times since now. This gives me the time between the date in `DateString` and now, however this is in days.

```
(datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.datetime.strptime(DateString, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')).days
```

There are instances where I have 0 days but also 100 days. How would I correctly choose the unit for any given `DateString`? *The options of units must **only** include seconds, minutes, days and weeks.*

Example:

```
>>> 10-03-2019 15:50:00
10 minutes ago

>>> 10-03-2019 08:00:00
8 hours ago
```

Comment: Hi. There is https://github.com/hustcc/timeago library for that.

Comment: Check out the documentation on [`datetime.timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects), which is the data type you're working with. It gives you seconds, which I'm confident you can manipulate to get what you're looking for.

Comment: @nmb.ten Thanks, but I can't use any external libraries - purely python and build-in libraries.